# Transcendental equation to solve in $x$: $\frac{(a^x)}{x}+(a^\frac{1}{x})x = 2a$, for any $a$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, transcendental-equations

First of all, sorry, that I didn't manage to write the equation with a proper editor:
$$
\frac{a^x}{x} + a^\frac{1}{x}x = 2a
$$
I know that $x=1$. It's easy. But I couldn't solve it.

I try two methods, but I am stuck with other equations:

First approach:
$$
a^x=y \qquad \text{and} \qquad a^{1/x}=z
$$
$$
x \ln{a}=\ln{y} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \ln{a}=x \ln{z}
$$
so 
$$
x = \frac{\ln{y}}{\ln{a}}=\frac{\ln{a}}{\ln{z}}
$$
so 
$$(\ln(y))(\ln(z))=(\ln(a))^2$$

Putting in the original equation I obtain the following system:

$$(\ln(y))(\ln(z))=(\ln(a))^2$$

and

$$z(\ln(y))+ y(\ln(z))= 2a(\ln(a))$$ or the equivalent

$$z/(\ln(z))+y/(\ln(y))= 2a/(\ln(a))$$

And if I try to use W lambert, I obtain something very... ugly.

Second approach:

$$(a^x)/x + (a^{1/x})x = 2a$$

$$(a^{1/x})(x^2)+ (a^x) - 2ax =0$$

$$\ln((a^{1/x})(x^2))= \ln(2ax - a^x)$$

$$\ln((a^{1/x}))+ 2 (\ln (x)) = \ln(2ax - a^x)$$

$$(1/x)(\ln(a)) + 2 (\ln(x))= \ln (2ax - a^x)$$

$$\ln(a) + 2 (\ln (x)) = x \ln (2ax - a^x)$$

$$\ln(a(x^2))= \ln(2ax - a^x)^x)$$

$$a(x^2)= (2ax- a^x)^x$$

If I try to use W lambert, I obtain again, an ugly equation...

Someone to help me?

Thank you.

Comment: The equation must hold $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I see no reason to suppose this is solvable using Lambert W.  If $a>0, a\ne 1$ then the LHS has a minimum at $x=1$, so $x=1$ is the unique positive real solution.

Comment: Yes the equation must hold for any real, a.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but since he has to find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{a^x}{x} + a^\frac{1}{x}x = 2a$, $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$, couldn't he just let $a=1$ to get that $x=1$ and he is done?

Comment: But if a=2, x=1, either... In fact even if a=c+di, x=1. On the other hand, if I write the same equation with different coefficients, I still don't know how to solve it. e.g.: x*(4^x) + (1/x)*(4^(1/x))=12... In this case x=0.5 and x=2.

Answer (score 4):

By AM-GM,

$$\frac{a^x}{x}+\frac{a^{1/x}}{1/x} \geq 2a^{\frac{x+1/x}{2}} \geq 2a$$ provided $a > 1$, with equality iff $x+x^{-1}=2$ iff $x=1$.

If $a < 1$, by weighed AM-GM, let $s=x+x^{-1}$, then

$$LHS \geq sa^{xx^{-1}/s}a^{x^{-1}x/s} = sa^{2/s}.$$

Since $s \geq 2$ and $a < 1$, $sa^{2/s} \geq 2a$ with equality iff $s=2$ iff $x=1$.